# Spring: Fire some method on default logout event

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In spring MVC if a user is not active since long time he is logout out by default as session timed out.

If a user is logged in and browser is closed then also he is logout.

I have implemented `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` to capture logout success. But it only fires when user click logout link manually.

How can i fire some method when login session expire or user is logged out by default (e.g on window close) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch a session expire with a [HttpSessionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

```java
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) { }
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        SecurityContext securityContext = (SecurityContext)session.getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY);
        // check for null, retrieve Authentication etc
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register your listener on startup.

It's hard to catch window close, but the session will expire in time.

Comment: will it be fire oon logout also?

Comment: @Manish Probably, depending on config.

Comment: what kind of configuration u r talking about.

Comment: @Manish `invalidate-session` attribute on `logout` element.